# Recursive best way length calculation for maze solver - error

Tags: c, recursion, solver, maze

i'm trying to determine the length of the fast way for a maze (a tridimensional maze), so, the one with lower length. I have done the fallowing code(u is a point where you can go up and d a point where you can go down):

```
typedef struct _parking {
int depth;
int width;
int height;
int entrances;
int exits;
int park_slots;
int available_park_slots;
local *** floors;

}parking;
typedef struct _local {
char type;
    char name[5];
int percorrido;
}local;

int bestlength = 99999999;

int DFS_ponto_carro(parking * parklot, int x, int y, int z, int a, int b, int c, int percorridos){
(parklot->floors[x][y][z]).percorrido = 1;
if(percorridos >= bestlength){
    return 30;
}
if ((x+1)==a && y==b && z==c){
    printf("cheguei aqui 1\n");
    bestlength = percorridos;
    return 30;
}
if ((x-1)==a && y==b && z==c){
    printf("cheguei aqui 2\n");
    bestlength = percorridos;
    return 30;
}
if (x==a && (y+1)==b && z==c){
    printf("cheguei aqui 3\n");
    bestlength = percorridos;
    return 30;
}
if (x==a && (y-1)==b && z==c){
    printf("cheguei aqui 4\n");
    bestlength = percorridos;
    return 30;
}
if(x != parklot->width-1){
    if((parklot->floors[x+1][y][z]).type == ' ' && (parklot->floors[x+1][y][z]).percorrido == -1){
        DFS_ponto_carro(parklot, x+1, y, z, a, b, c, percorridos++);
    }
    if((parklot->floors[x+1][y][z]).type == 'u' && (parklot->floors[x+1][y][z]).percorrido == -1){
        DFS_ponto_carro(parklot, x+1, y, z+1, a, b, c, percorridos++);

    }
    if((parklot->floors[x+1][y][z]).type == 'd' && (parklot->floors[x+1][y][z]).percorrido == -1){
        DFS_ponto_carro(parklot, x+1, y, z-1, a, b, c, percorridos++);
    }
}
if(y != 0){
    if((parklot->floors[x][y-1][z]).type == ' ' && (parklot->floors[x][y-1][z]).percorrido == -1){
        DFS_ponto_carro(parklot, x, y-1, z, a, b, c, percorridos++);
    }
    if((parklot->floors[x][y-1][z]).type == 'u' && (parklot->floors[x][y-1][z]).percorrido == -1){
        DFS_ponto_carro(parklot, x, y-1, z+1, a, b, c, percorridos++);
    }
    if((parklot->floors[x][y-1][z]).type == 'd' && (parklot->floors[x][y-1][z]).percorrido == -1){
        DFS_ponto_carro(parklot, x, y-1, z-1, a, b, c, percorridos++);
    }
}
if(x != 0){
    if((parklot->floors[x-1][y][z]).type == ' ' && (parklot->floors[x-1][y][z]).percorrido == -1){
        DFS_ponto_carro(parklot, x-1, y, z, a, b, c, percorridos++);
    }
    if((parklot->floors[x-1][y][z]).type == 'u' && (parklot->floors[x-1][y][z]).percorrido == -1){
        DFS_ponto_carro(parklot, x-1, y, z+1, a, b, c, percorridos++);
    }
    if((parklot->floors[x-1][y][z]).type == 'd' && (parklot->floors[x-1][y][z]).percorrido == -1){
        DFS_ponto_carro(parklot, x-1, y, z-1, a, b, c, percorridos++);
    }
}
if(y != parklot->height-1){
    if((parklot->floors[x][y+1][z]).type == ' ' && (parklot->floors[x][y+1][z]).percorrido == -1){
        DFS_ponto_carro(parklot, x, y+1, z, a, b, c, percorridos++);
    }
    if((parklot->floors[x][y+1][z]).type == 'u' && (parklot->floors[x][y+1][z]).percorrido == -1){
        DFS_ponto_carro(parklot, x, y+1, z+1, a, b, c, percorridos++);
    }
    if((parklot->floors[x][y+1][z]).type == 'd' && (parklot->floors[x][y+1][z]).percorrido == -1){
        DFS_ponto_carro(parklot, x, y+1, z-1, a, b, c, percorridos++);
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

The code is giving me a segmentation fault in the last return, but i can't seem to find out why, could someone help me?

Comment: Post the declaration of the `parking` type and any relevant definitions for a minimum compilable example.

Comment: You're repeating a lot of logic. It might help you to reason about what is happening if you didn't brute force all those permutations and found a better abstraction.

Comment: Just edited code, put the definitions...I think that the problem is from stack overflow, but how can i be sure?

Comment: Why do you post-increment `percorridos` for each recursive call instead of just passing `percorridos+1` ?

Comment: I've changed for what you said, percorrido+1, it solved the problem for some time....but when the exit is more far from the entrance, the code still crashes with segmentation fault

Answer (score 0):

You call `DFS_ponto_carro` recursively with values for `z` that might be out of range: namely `z-1` and `z+1`. The first thing you do in the recursive call is dereferencing `parklot->floors[x][y][z]`.  How do you ensure that `z` stays within array boundaries?

Comment: That will never happen, as you can see by the code, it only goes up when there is u and only goes down when the map has a d (this are ramps). So, in the last floor there isn't a ramp going down and the first floor there isn't a ramp going down....so everything is ok! I'm thinking that tthe problem is from an overflow...

Comment: How do you allocate the structures?  How do invoke the function?